# Getting REST API results in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get a specific value out of a JSON file in PHP how could this be done. I'm trying to find the value of `"allTests": [{"TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true}]` in the code below and check if it is there and if it equals to true. the value can be true or false and 'TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken' can be also 'TestOnBlazemeterFailed' or 'TestOnBlazemeterWasSuccessful' it depends on the success of an API test

The json file from where i need  to find the value `"allTests": [{"TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true}]`

```
{
    "id": "311e6d5a-3f20-42d2-b276-80c5f33f1d7f",
    "name": "Testing",
    "timestamp": "2021-07-02T10:39:48.544Z",
    "collection_id": "6cd6e3b9-cce9-4746-83ca-9349708d3b18",
    "folder_id": 0,
    "environment_id": "db26e19d-4373-4004-9ad2-348545c6f521",
    "totalPass": 1,
    "totalFail": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "bb1b9473-2f66-4153-8996-88cf40715ba6",
            "name": "retrieving ID's",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests?workspaceId=894576&limit=20&hasExecutions=true&filterByActivePlatform=false",
            "time": 1116,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                1116
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "c694f16e-8195-4696-a874-fdaed51bbfd7",
            "name": "Session summary1",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9661550/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 259,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                259
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "e80d222f-89fe-45cd-a139-6d1b0cfafece",
            "name": "Session summary2",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9595495/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 442,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                442
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "4b129897-0241-465b-94dc-29814808442e",
            "name": "Session summary3",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9595540/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 319,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                319
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "bd17cd20-7165-48e0-8a03-c2d95affc4d1",
            "name": "Session summary4",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9595539/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 593,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                593
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "557c971f-f918-49f1-9d69-7c9547bfe504",
            "name": "Session summary5",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9595355/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 337,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                337
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "8dd94fcc-d04c-43ac-9793-ba0351a41a9d",
            "name": "Get master id",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/sessions/r-sg-60dc87126dd20190458039",
            "time": 259,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                259
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "201bd700-de90-45b7-83f6-06b8c7322727",
            "name": "See the masters test",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/masters/35589479",
            "time": 284,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {
                "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true
            },
            "testPassFailCounts": {
                "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": {
                    "pass": 1,
                    "fail": 0
                }
            },
            "times": [
                284
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {
                    "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "count": 1,
    "totalTime": 3609,
    "collection": {
        "requests": [
            {
                "id": "bb1b9473-2f66-4153-8996-88cf40715ba6",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "c694f16e-8195-4696-a874-fdaed51bbfd7",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "e80d222f-89fe-45cd-a139-6d1b0cfafece",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "4b129897-0241-465b-94dc-29814808442e",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "bd17cd20-7165-48e0-8a03-c2d95affc4d1",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "557c971f-f918-49f1-9d69-7c9547bfe504",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "8dd94fcc-d04c-43ac-9793-ba0351a41a9d",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "201bd700-de90-45b7-83f6-06b8c7322727",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The part I'm looking for is `"allTests": [{"TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true}]` how could I find this value and check if it is there and if it equals to true.

```
{
            "id": "201bd700-de90-45b7-83f6-06b8c7322727",
            "name": "See the masters test",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/masters/35589479",
            "time": 284,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {
                "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true
            },
            "testPassFailCounts": {
                "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": {
                    "pass": 1,
                    "fail": 0
                }
            },
            "times": [
                284
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {
                    "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true
                }
            ]
        }
```

I have tried this but it didn't work - and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11

Code:

```
<?php

    // Read JSON file
    $json = file_get_contents('Testing.postman_test_run.json');

    //Decode JSON
    $json_data = json_decode($json,true);

    //Traverse array and get the data for students aged less than 20
    foreach ($json_data as $key1 => $value1) {
        if($json_data[$key1]["allTests"][7]['TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken'] == true){
            print_r($json_data[$key1]);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please add the code that you have currently

Comment: Please post your actual attempt instead of just link to the guide it's _based_ on (which doesn't tell us anything about _your_ code since you can have rewrites/typos etc). You should also explain what "didn't work" means. What _actually_ happens? You also say _"repeats 6 more times"_, does that mean that all these actually are wrapped inside an array? We need to know the _exact_ format here.

Comment: The above extracts of data show different results. Can the actual result data include both - or more - or will there be a single result?

Comment: there is gonna be only one result  `"TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true` or `"TestOnBlazemeterFailed":true` or `"TestOnBlazemeterWasSuccessful":true`

Comment: This code is only for this json output: ``echo array_reverse(json_decode($k, true)["results"])[0]["allTests"][0]["TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken"]; // true``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following ought to work OK whether there is one or more results.

```
$str='{
    "id": "311e6d5a-3f20-42d2-b276-80c5f33f1d7f",
    "name": "Testing",
    "timestamp": "2021-07-02T10:39:48.544Z",
    "collection_id": "6cd6e3b9-cce9-4746-83ca-9349708d3b18",
    "folder_id": 0,
    "environment_id": "db26e19d-4373-4004-9ad2-348545c6f521",
    "totalPass": 1,
    "totalFail": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "bb1b9473-2f66-4153-8996-88cf40715ba6",
            "name": "retrieving IDs",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests?workspaceId=894576&limit=20&hasExecutions=true&filterByActivePlatform=false",
            "time": 1116,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                1116
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "201bd700-de90-45b7-83f6-06b8c7322727",
            "name": "See the masters test",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/masters/35589479",
            "time": 284,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {
                "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true
            },
            "testPassFailCounts": {
                "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": {
                    "pass": 1,
                    "fail": 0
                }
            },
            "times": [
                284
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {
                    "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';

$fail=false;
$testname='TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken';

$json=json_decode( $str );
$results=$json->results ?: false;

if( $results ){
    foreach( $results as $result ){
        if( property_exists( $result, 'allTests' ) ){
            foreach( $result->allTests as $test ){
                if( property_exists( $test, $testname ) && $test->$testname==true ){
                    $fail=true;
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$status=$fail ? 'Failed! ' : 'Passed!';
printf( 'The test "%s" was %s', $testname, $status );
```

Given the above `$str` data this will yield `"The test "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken" was Failed!"` because within one of the results the specific test was found and evaluated to true.

---

Given the source data ( saved as `blaze-test.json` )

```
{
    "id": "311e6d5a-3f20-42d2-b276-80c5f33f1d7f",
    "name": "Testing",
    "timestamp": "2021-07-02T10:39:48.544Z",
    "collection_id": "6cd6e3b9-cce9-4746-83ca-9349708d3b18",
    "folder_id": 0,
    "environment_id": "db26e19d-4373-4004-9ad2-348545c6f521",
    "totalPass": 1,
    "totalFail": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "bb1b9473-2f66-4153-8996-88cf40715ba6",
            "name": "retrieving ID's",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests?workspaceId=894576&limit=20&hasExecutions=true&filterByActivePlatform=false",
            "time": 1116,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                1116
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "c694f16e-8195-4696-a874-fdaed51bbfd7",
            "name": "Session summary1",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9661550/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 259,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                259
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "e80d222f-89fe-45cd-a139-6d1b0cfafece",
            "name": "Session summary2",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9595495/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 442,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                442
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "4b129897-0241-465b-94dc-29814808442e",
            "name": "Session summary3",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9595540/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 319,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                319
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "bd17cd20-7165-48e0-8a03-c2d95affc4d1",
            "name": "Session summary4",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9595539/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 593,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                593
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "557c971f-f918-49f1-9d69-7c9547bfe504",
            "name": "Session summary5",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/tests/9595355/sessions-summaries",
            "time": 337,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                337
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "8dd94fcc-d04c-43ac-9793-ba0351a41a9d",
            "name": "Get master id",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/sessions/r-sg-60dc87126dd20190458039",
            "time": 259,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {},
            "testPassFailCounts": {},
            "times": [
                259
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "201bd700-de90-45b7-83f6-06b8c7322727",
            "name": "See the masters test",
            "url": "https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/masters/35589479",
            "time": 284,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            },
            "tests": {
                "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true
            },
            "testPassFailCounts": {
                "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": {
                    "pass": 1,
                    "fail": 0
                }
            },
            "times": [
                284
            ],
            "allTests": [
                {
                    "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "count": 1,
    "totalTime": 3609,
    "collection": {
        "requests": [
            {
                "id": "bb1b9473-2f66-4153-8996-88cf40715ba6",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "c694f16e-8195-4696-a874-fdaed51bbfd7",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "e80d222f-89fe-45cd-a139-6d1b0cfafece",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "4b129897-0241-465b-94dc-29814808442e",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "bd17cd20-7165-48e0-8a03-c2d95affc4d1",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "557c971f-f918-49f1-9d69-7c9547bfe504",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "8dd94fcc-d04c-43ac-9793-ba0351a41a9d",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "id": "201bd700-de90-45b7-83f6-06b8c7322727",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The processing script:

```
// Fetch the data from local file in same directory
$str=file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/blaze-test.json' );

// set the test and result status default - assume pass unless specific fail
$fail=false;
$testname='TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken';

// decode the string data so we can work with it
$json=json_decode( $str );
$results=$json->results ?: false;


if( $results ){
    //iterate through the results
    foreach( $results as $result ){
        
        $name=$result->name;
        $code=$result->responseCode->code;
        
        if( property_exists( $result, 'allTests' ) ){
            foreach( $result->allTests as $test ){
                // does the test exist in the data and was it failed?
                if( property_exists( $test, $testname ) && $test->$testname==true ){
                    $fail=true;
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    $status=$fail ? 'Failed' : 'Passed';
    printf(
        '
        <style>
            .Failed{color:red}
            .Passed{color:green}
        </style>
        <h2>Tests run: %d</h2>
        <p>The test "%s" within "%s" was <span class="%s">%s</span> with code %s!</p>',
        count($results),
        $testname,
        $name,
        $status,
        $status,
        $code
    );
}
```

The result:

```
Tests run: 8
The test "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken" within "See the masters test" was Failed with code 200!
```

Comment: I don't have the actual data as a file to test with - does the real data differ from the data you added to the question?

Comment: I just tried the code it works only when the JSON part is writen in the php file, but the JSON is a seperate file. Tried to change this `$json=json_decode('/Testing.postman_test_run.json');` so it would search in this specific  file the files will change but their names wount. the response i get is this "Warning: Attempt to read property "results" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7
The test "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken" was Passed!" no matter if "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken" is true or "TestOnBlazemeterWasSuccessful":true

Comment: the only difference is that "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken":true  swapped to "TestOnBlazemeterWasSuccessful":true

Comment: The data is directly coppied from the file

Comment: OK. I created a new file called `blaze-test.json` within the same directory as the test script. I called this file using `$str=file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/blaze-test.json' );` and ran the script. The test `TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken`  was NOT in that particular testfile and the script ran 100% OK

Comment: When I edited that same file to include the data as shown in my answer (ie: 2 test results) and ran the script it ran perfectly and yielded the result I gave in the answer - fail!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your data.

First (if you do not *see it* in json) you may look at the array.

So just print it (f.e. `echo var_export($json_data, true) . PHP_EOL; die;`)
or write it into an file.

Looks ok? Then build the loop.

First you loop through the array at the `result` offset.

And if you do not know what you get on one result then do the same as previously: look at it. Print it.
*Same for any deeper loops.*

The loop:

```
// Read JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('Testing.postman_test_run.json');

//Decode JSON
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

//Traverse array and get the data for students aged less than 20
foreach ($json_data['results'] as $result) {
    foreach ($result["allTests"] as $test) {
        if (isset($test['TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken'])
            and $test['TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken'] === true
        ) {
            // You found it and its true.
            echo "TestOnBlazemeterWasBroken is true at {$result['id']}\r\n";
            // May collect or print or w/e.
        }
    }
}
```